# Visual Studio Style ToolStrip Panels

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am starting to learn to use Visual Studio and its form designer. I've got a tool strip container working with moveable tool strips but I want to create a tool strip that when clicked opens up a panel. e.g. visual studios solution explorer, properties panel.

Here's some pictures of what I mean:

Example of tool strip panel "Solution Explorer" minimized
[image: Example of tool strip panel minimized]

Example of tool strip panel "Solution Explorer" maximized
[image: Example of tool strip panel maximized]

So how can I get this behavior in my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [DockPanel suite](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) that used to be quite popular, which is a free third-party control.

At work we use the [Devexpress DockPanel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockPaneltopic) for this, but there's a price attached here.

Comment: This looks good but I cant get it to work. I'm running the sample project but I get a System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException error. I'm using the DockPanel suite. Have you used it before?

Comment: I haven't, but I just gave it a spin. It works fine here. I used the Nuget package to install it (version 2.9.0.0). [This tutorial](http://www.websofia.com/2013/03/weifenluo-dockpanelsuite-tutorial-cookbook/) might be of help as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ill have a look at the nuget installer to :)

Comment: Got it working! Solution works great and exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you :)